# Função GET no ng-click

Tags: angularjs

Preciso chamar uma função `GET` através do ng-click para popular uma tabela e a função sem usar service funciona, mas a função usando service não funciona.

Controller:

Funciona

```
$scope.carregarContratos = function() {
    $http({method: 'GET', url: config.baseUrl + '/contratos'})
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.contratos = response.data;
    }, function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        console.log(response.status);
    });
};
```

Não funciona

```
carregarContratosPaginados = function (pageNumber) {
    ContratosAPI.getContratosPaginados(pageNumber, $scope.usersPerPage).success(function (data) {
        $scope.contratos = data;
        $scope.totalContratos = 100;
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        $scope.message = "Aconteceu um problema: " + data;
    });
};
```

Service:

```
angular.module("myapp").factory("ContratosAPI", function ($http, config) {
    var _getContratos = function () {
        return $http.get(config.baseUrl + "/contratos");
    };

    var _getContratosPaginados = function (pagina, total) {
        return $http.get(config.baseUrl + "/contratos?pagina=" + pagina + "&total=" + total);
    };

    var _saveContrato = function (contrato) {
        return $http.post(config.baseUrl + "/contratos", contrato);
    };

    return {
        getContratos: _getContratos,
        getContratosPaginados: _getContratosPaginados,
        saveContrato: _saveContrato
    };
});
```

ng-click:

```
ng-click="carregarContratosPaginados(1)"
```

Comment: Ao invés de usar o método "success" na sua chamada "getContratosPaginados", use o ".then()" e veja o que retorna na variável "data". Se der erro, poste o erro aqui também.

Comment: Com o .then() e carregando direto funciona, mas no ng-click não. Não mostrou nenhum erro. O ng-click está assim: `ng-click="carregarContratosPaginados(1)"`

Comment: cara, não tá faltando um `$scope` na declaração da sua função não? Deveria ser `$scope.carregarContratosPaginados = function (pageNumber)...`

Comment: @Sorack Nossa, era isso mesmo, eu não declarei a função com $scope no controller, agora funcionou com o ng-click também. Não acredito que errei nisso haha. Aproveitando, é melhor usar .then ou .success? Obrigado!

Comment: Sobre o `then` ou `success`, depende de como você quer tratar os erros. Eu particularmente prefiro o `then` porque fica mais parecido com outras apis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Está faltando o `$scope` antes da declaração do seu método para que seja visível para a view:

```
$scope.carregarContratosPaginados = function (pageNumber)...
```